# Is it possible to create a type that is an enum of some interval?

Tags: postgresql, types, enums

How to make a new TYPE with ENUM that takes all of the members of an interval? Like:

```
CREATE TYPE letters [a...z]
```

Comment: Why do you think you need that? If you want to constrain the values of a column, a check constraint is probably the better choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [no built-in syntax for this](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-enum.html), but you can do it with dynamic SQL:

```
DO
$$
BEGIN
EXECUTE
   (
   SELECT 'CREATE TYPE a2z AS ENUM ('''
       || string_agg(chr(ascii('a') + g), ''',''')
       || ''')'
   FROM   generate_series(0,25) g
   );
END
$$;
```

This builds and executes a statement of the form:

```
CREATE TYPE a2z AS ENUM ('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z')
```

This depends on your locale, but I think that all locales have `a-z` in a continuous range, which is all that's needed for this. Tested with an UTF-8 locale.

#### Alternative for anything that won't easily fit into an `ENUM`

For long lists of values, values that tend to change or are not as simple as the example or for special data types etc. consider creating a small **look-up table** instead and use a [**foreign key constraint**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK) to it. Example for a selection of dates:

```
CREATE TABLE my_date (my_date date PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO my_date(my_date) VALUES ('2015-02-03'), ...;

CREATE TABLE foo (
  foo_id serial PRIMARY KEY
, my_date date REFERENCES my_date ON UPDATE CASCADE
--,  more columns ...
);
```

Comment: My first problem is to insert a column ''years. No way with the date types. Have to do by an another way... Then, I can  do as you said.

Comment: @Cipango: I have answered your question fair and square. No mention of a `date` type. If you have another question, please start another question. And be sure to be clear about what you need.

Comment: Thanks, i don t want to ask a new question about this. I know my question was not about date type. Thinking about this problem of dates, I realized this problem. And I pleased your answer. Thank s a lot. ps: I m new in this place, sorry if I make mistakes...